# AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'android_add_dependency'

Tags: android, admob, game-engine, ads, godot

I'm trying to compile godot with this module: admob

https://github.com/kloder-games/godot-admob

But I have this error when I compile:

```
scons platform=android target=release android_arch=arm64v8
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Building for Android (arm64v8)
WARNING: android_arch=arm64v8 is not supported by ndk_platform lower than android-21; setting         ndk_platform=android-21
Using NDK unified headers
Warning: module 'admob' uses a deprecated `can_build` signature in its config.py file, it should be `can_build(env, platform)`.
AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'android_add_dependency':
  File "D:\Backup\Download\godot-master\godot-master\SConstruct", line 403:
config.configure(env)
File "./modules/admob\config.py", line 6:
env.android_add_dependency("compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0') { exclude group: 'com.android.support' }")
```

what is?